# VSTS 2010 Debug Feature

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I heard of a feature supposedly included in VSTS 2010, but now I can't find any mention of it.

It was a tool that allowed a developer to attach a debugger that was on a flash/jump drive and start debugging a program.  It did not require any installation.

Note: I am not referring to the Historical Debugger.

Anyone else heard of this?  Anyone know of the name of it it, or a link to something about it?

Maybe it was all a dream....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It certainly existed as part of VS2010 story some time ago. A few links that mention it:

- [http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/maordavid/archive/2008/04/21/Rosario-Preview-_2300_3-*2D00*-Developer-Edition.aspx](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/maordavid/archive/2008/04/21/Rosario-Preview-_2300_3-_2D00_-Developer-Edition.aspx)
- http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2008/09/29/its-official-visual-studio-2010-and-net-framework-40.aspx
- http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2008/10/01/are-you-ready-for-visual-studio-2010.aspx
- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vstsrosario/thread/651f1e45-6980-45c2-878d-b6b84e801f3e
- http://dotnet.org.za/willy/archive/2008/06/06/rosario-april-ctp-investigation-part-6-developer.aspx
- https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=362455&wa=wsignin1.0

I do not know what is the present state of the feature - I don't see it listed in more recent "What's new in VS2010" MSDN articles.

Comment: Looks like most people were calling it the Standalone Debugger